# The difference between `sess.graph` and `tf.get_default_graph()`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

`sess.graph` and `tf.get_default_graph()` gives the same results in tensorboard. It is not very clear to me what is the difference between them according to the manual. Could anybody help explain the difference? Could anyboby provide an example for which `sess.graph` and `tf.get_default_graph()` can not be used interchangeably?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

import tensorflow as tf
import sys

x = tf.Variable(1.0)
with tf.name_scope('ns_loss'):
    loss = tf.square(x)
with tf.name_scope('ns_adam'):
    train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

tf.summary.scalar('scalar_loss', loss)
merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir=sys.argv[1])
    summary_writer.add_graph(graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    #summary_writer.add_graph(graph=sess.graph)

    for i in xrange(100):
        sess.run(train_op)
        summary_writer.add_summary(
                summary = sess.run(merged_summary_op)
                , global_step = i
                )
```

Answer (score 4):

[`tf.get_default_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_default_graph) always returns the current computation graph. E.g., it is the graph where `x` and `loss` nodes are defined even before the session has started.

When you create a session with [`tf.Session()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#__init__) you can optionally specify a non-default graph to work with. In your example, it's not specified:

> If no `graph` argument is specified when constructing the session, the
>   default graph will be launched in the session.

It's rate to have multiple graphs in one script, but possible, for instance, when a graph is restored from the disk.

Also note that after the session is done, the default graph is still there, so their lifetime is different.